# 'Knockout Tournament' Software to Pick Best Image?

Tags: windows, images

Is there a program available with the following features:

- Load a folder of images
- Randomly select 2 images from said folder and present them side by side for comparison
- Allow me to choose the best image from the selection and save it for a later 'round'
- Eventually allow me to narrow each folder down to one image, ostensibly the 'best' image in that folder
- Lightweight (optional)

Really what I am asking for is a knockout tournament for my photos in order to pick my favourite in any given folder.

Currently I am generating images using Stable Diffusion, and narrowing down similar images can be a pain.

I thought this would be a fun way of looking through my photos generally too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you find a native pairwise comparison tool. This will not knock out images but it will compare images in several rounds. It will generate a relative ranking. So instead of having a last surviver image you have a winning image. We do this in a online voting tool (https://pollunit.com/en/pairwise-comparison) but this would require you to upload images. But maybe this points you in an alternative direction which could help you.